# Custom activity feed notifications sent from daemon(nodejs app), not getting the data assigned to subEntityId in teams mobile client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I'm using activityFeedNotification graph api to send push notification to the users of our teams tab app from backend using nodejs. The notification is sending successfully in both teams desktop and mobile client but we're not getting the data assigned to subEntityId in mobile client(In desktop client and browser we're getting it).

We are encoding the `data(object)` and assigning it to the `subEntityId` in teams context in our nodejs application. Then in teams client, we get that data from teams context using microsoft teams sdk and redirect user to the respective page in our application based on whatever data we get in `subEntityId`

In desktop, deeplinking is working perfectly but in android client, we're not getting any data in `subEntityId`. It is just opening the homepage of our tab app but I need to redirect user to specific page based whatever data is assigned to `subEntityId`.

Below I've provided how we're encoding the `data` and assigning it to `subEntityId`.

**Server Side:**

```
const context = encodeURIComponent(
      JSON.stringify({
        "subEntityId": {
         "type": "PROGRAM_PROFILE",
         "program_id": "12345",
          uid: uuidv4(),
        }
      })
    );

const body = {
  topic: {
    source: 'text',
    value: notificationTopic,
    webUrl: `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${TEAMS_APP_ID}/index?context=${context}`,
  },
  activityType: 'commonNotification',
  previewText: {
    content: notificationSubtitle,
  },
  templateParameters: [
    {
      name: 'title',
      value: notificationTitle,
    },
  ],
};

const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}/teamwork/sendActivityNotification`;

await axios.post(url, body));
```

**Client Side:**

```
const context = await app.getContext();
console.log(context?.page?.subPageId); // getting undefined
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=teamsjs-v2):

[{page.subPageId}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/app.pageinfo?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-app-pageinfo-subpageid): The developer-defined unique ID for the subpage this content points defined when generating a deep link for a specific item within the page. (Known as `{subEntityId}` prior to TeamsJS v.2.0.0).

You are using `subEntityId` on the backend but accessing `subPageId` on the client side.

Comment: subEntityId in backend becomes subPageId in client. Deep linking is working fine in desktop client and browser (I'm getting data in subPageId) but in mobile client it becomes undefined. Seems like a bug in teams js SDK.

Comment: This issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/1518). Please follow that thread for further updates. Thanks!